# pip install slackclient on OSX 10.11.1

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, slack-api, slack

My question is two-fold:

1) When I try `pip install slackclient`
I'm eventually thrown this error: `error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/websocket': Permission denied`

To get around this I then tried: `sudo pip install websocket` which eventually throws this error: `error: could not create '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/greenlet': Operation not permitted`

At this point I searched around a bit and found a cryptic page on github saying to do a `pip install --user` and that this error was the result of some issue with my version of OSX not allowing even root level access to some areas.  I don't really follow this argument and so after little more information found on the web gave up on the error and didn't attempt the `pip install --user`.

What is the right thing to do here?

2) After reaching the last error in the above point, I gave up and tried `sudo pip install slackclient` and everything magically installed without errors.
Was this okay to do or will I regret this in some way down the road?

Thanks!